# UITextField refuses to allow user input

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uitextfield

I've set up a `UITextField` in Interface Builder and connected it with the property `self.nameField`.  My problem is that, as is, tapping it does nothing--the user can't enter any text; there isn't even a cursor.  If I add `becomeFirstResponder` then the keyboard automatically displays.  What I want is for the keyboard to display if and only if the user taps the field to enter text.

The method involved is as follows:

```
-(void)displayOptOutScreen
{
    if (!self.nameField)
    {
        self.nameField=[[UITextField alloc] init];
    }
    self.nameField.hidden=NO;
    self.nameField.delegate = self;
    self.nameField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [self textFieldShouldReturn:self.nameField];
    [self.textView resignFirstResponder]; //This is a UITextView, created programmatically
    //[self.nameField becomeFirstResponder];  //Keyboard automatically displays.
}
```

For what it's worth, there's a `UIButton` that also isn't accepting touches.  The `UITextView` is accepting text with no problem.

This is a tabbed application.  After reading over other Stack Overflow questions, I've tried adding various combinations of the following lines to the app delegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[GHHaikuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GHHaikuViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but I get various errors depending on which lines I include or not, and nothing ends up working.  (The view controller the `UITextField` is on is not `GHHaikuViewController` but `GHComposeViewController`, but I get an error when I try to use that instead.)

Any thoughts about what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**  Here are screen shots of the Interface Builder settings.  Sorry they're broken up--I'm working on a MacBook Air 11".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**FURTHER EDIT:**  Here's the output when I entered `po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] recursiveDescription]` at the debug prompt.

```
(id) $1 = 0x0ad4bb80 <UIWindow: 0xad48ac0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0xad44010>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x9e74450; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e74510>>
   |    | <UITransitionView: 0xaa46f80; frame = (0 0; 320 431); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xaa47050>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x9e90760; frame = (0 20; 320 411); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e907c0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x9e8c870; frame = (0 0; 320 411); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9e8bbd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e8c8d0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x9e8c790; frame = (0 0; 320 411); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e8c7f0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UITextField: 0x9e82610; frame = (40 189; 240 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9e6ea90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e83720>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundView: 0x9e73ac0; frame = (0 0; 240 30); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e73b80>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x9e73cd0; frame = (0 0; 8 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e73d30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x9e73d80; frame = (8 0; 224 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e73de0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x9e73e10; frame = (232 0; 8 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e73e70>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x9e8afa0; frame = (7 7; 226 15); text = 'Name (optional)'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e8af20>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0xad6fb00; frame = (236 221; 44 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xad6fbf0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x9e921c0; frame = (14 14; 16 16); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e922d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x9e8a6f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e8a790>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UITextView: 0xa3de800; frame = (20 90; 300 480); text = '
I hope to update the May...'; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9e72ef0>; animations = { transition=<CATransition: 0x9e8eea0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x9e5d770>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIWebDocumentView: 0xa3dec00; frame = (0 0; 300 188); text = '
I hope to update the May...'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9e8d5a0>; layer = <UIWebLayer: 0x9e8d220>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TileHostLayer: 0x9e8d2b0> (layer)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <TileLayer: 0x9e90fb0> (layer)
   |    | <UITabBar: 0xad41b80; frame = (0 431; 320 49); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xad41c70>>
   |    |    | <_UITabBarBackgroundView: 0xad47950; frame = (0 0; 320 49); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad47a00>>
   |    |    | <UITabBarButton: 0xad42ff0; frame = (2 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad453e0>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarSwappableImageView: 0xad45670; frame = (14 2; 48 32); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad45740>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarButtonLabel: 0xad42410; frame = (24 34; 28 13); text = 'Home'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad42500>>
   |    |    | <UITabBarButton: 0xad46b10; frame = (82 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad46460>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarSelectionIndicatorView: 0xad5cf90; frame = (0 2; 76 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad5d2f0>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarSwappableImageView: 0xad46490; frame = (14 2; 48 32); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad46510>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarButtonLabel: 0xad46790; frame = (15 34; 46 13); text = 'Compose'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad40650>>
   |    |    | <UITabBarButton: 0xad46630; frame = (162 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad47080>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarButtonLabel: 0xad46df0; frame = (29 34; 19 13); text = 'Buy'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad466f0>>
   |    |    | <UITabBarButton: 0xad47270; frame = (242 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad47770>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarButtonLabel: 0xad47330; frame = (15 34; 47 13); text = 'Feedback'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad473d0>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xad48130; frame = (0 -3; 320 3); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xad48190>>
(lldb)
```

Comment: Take a screenshot of the hierarchy in Interface Builder on the left for that view controller with everything expanded please.

Comment: Done--it would be wonderful if I'd just screwed up some setting!

Comment: Sadly it doesn't appear so. When does this displayOptOut Method get called?

Comment: @JoelDerfner check the my answer , i have edited it , i hope it will fix the issue

Comment: Make sure both the userInteractionEnabled and enabled properties are set for your UITextField and UIButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're handling your UIControls correctly (having set all userInteractionEnabled properties to YES, for instance), this sounds as if you have set an invisible UIView on top of your UIControls.

Once your app is running in the simulator, you can check this manually by pausing the application (using the little pause button under your code) and typing this command in the debug prompt:

```
po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] recursiveDescription]
```

This will print out the description of the UIWindow and **all** of its subviews. You can check if there is a UIView on top of your UIControls somehow.

Comment: Where is the debug prompt?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the output of the command you suggested.  I don't understand it but I'm thinking it contains the answer I seek.  Can you help me interpret it and tell me what to do?

Comment: I ended up adding `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.nameField];` and that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Are the button and text field subviews of a view that's user-interaction disabled?

Comment: They don't seem to be, alas.  That would have been great--an easy fix.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(UIView *view in [self view].subViews){
    [view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem.  :(  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the frame of the text field when you create it from code

```
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
tf.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

also if you create it from xib file make sure that the **user interaction enabled** check is checked or in the view delegate

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [self.nameField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```